# Run conduit from exterior sconce

Tags: wiring, ceiling-fan, code-compliance, conduit, junction-box

We have a sconce on the outside of our brick house on a covered patio currently.  I would like to run conduit from it to allow us to place an exterior fan on the same covered porch.  My questions:
1) Can I add an exterior junction box and run conduit from it (all surface mounted) to the new fan placement, 
2) mount a new sconce on the junction box (hopefully covering most of the box)
3) Mount the fan to a fan rated exterior junction box which will be flush mounted to the ceiling joist?

I want to make sure this would be code and safety compliant.  Thank you.
Elmo

Comment: What size is the existing box?

Comment: Currently there isn’t even a pancake. I would have to put that in.

Comment: So the sconce is mounted to the wall without a box?

Comment: From what I can tell yes. However the wiring is the old rubber insulated wire that I don’t want to disturb until I’m ready to change everything out. It’s possible there is a pancake box. I pulled the fixture off gingerly and minimally because I knew it was the old wiring so I didn’t get the best look. If there isn’t one I’m going to have to put one in when I do this.

Comment: This doesn't address your main question, but just a heads up that you won't be able to switch the fan separately from the light with the setup you're talking about. You could use a pull cord or remote to turn the fan off while the light is on, but you won't be able to turn the fan on without also turning on the light.

Comment: So would it be code compl Any the way I want to set it up?

Answer (score 0):

Like many things the hard part with running that conduit is getting started.  A round box extension will work with your sconce and existing box, that will get you started:

[image: round outdoor extension Bell 5363-0]

If you don't have a box, just wires coming through the wall, you could use a regular round outdoor box surface mounted with the wires entering the KO in the back (with a fitting for the cable):

[image: round outdoor box Bell 5361-0]

Making it look right with the box between the sconce and the wall may be a challenge.  There are stone boxes that go around an electrical box, it could be surface mounted on the brick

[image: stone light box]

[image]

but you would have a hard time drilling that for conduit.  It would probably be easier to build a wood box around the electrical box to make a flat mounting surface for the sconce, or you could switch a different light.

Comment: I think thIs is a great way to hide the boxes. Do I need to worry about condensation within the boxes?  Would the plan of running exposed conduit and hanging the fan off of a fan box be ok code wise?

Comment: If you use the stone box, there may be a gasket on the sconce that goes between the stone box and the fixture to seal out water.  I am not sure if your patio would be classified as a wet or damp location by NEC, but it's easy enough to use wire and connectors rated for wet locations if in doubt.  Most wire is dual rated THHN THWN so that is OK, and you can buy wet location wire nuts which are packed with a silicone gel for small extra cost.